# Using mysql as nosql using memcached - Table not updating

Tags: mysql, memcached, nosql

I am new to using nosql in mysql

I have installed and enabled the memcahed interface and then followed these stpes:

-Created a new table 'users'

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test.users (
  `user_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

-Added it to the contaoners table.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO containers 
(name, db_schema, db_table, key_columns,
value_columns, unique_idx_name_on_key)
VALUES ('default', 'test', 'users', 'user_id', 'first|last', 'PRIMARY');

mysql> select * from innodb_memcache.containers;
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------------------+
| name    | db_schema | db_table  | key_columns | value_columns | flags | cas_column | expire_time_column | unique_idx_name_on_key |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------------------+
| aaa     | test      | demo_test | c1          | c2            | c3    | c4         | c5                 | PRIMARY                |
| default | test      | users     | user_id     | first|last    | 0     | NULL       | NULL               | PRIMARY                |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-started the interface using telnet and ran the following command to store values to the table.

```
set foo 0 0 14
Jarvis|Badgley
```

-Now get foo gives the stored result

```
get foo
VALUE foo 0 14
Jarvis|Badgley
END
```

- But when I check the mysql table these values are not stored.

```
mysql> select * from test.users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not ale to get why the updated values are no reflected in the tables.

Please Help!

Comment: how do you connect mysql to memcached or vice versa?

Comment: I have installed the mysql plugin daemon_memcached `INSTALL PLUGIN daemon_memcached SONAME 'libmemcached.so';`  and then started the memcached interface using telnet

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to make it work, following your steps but with some fixes.

First of all, user table definition is wrong (column `id` does not exist). It should be:

```
CREATE TABLE test.users (
  `user_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

If you configure this table:

```
INSERT INTO containers 
(name, db_schema, db_table, key_columns,
value_columns, unique_idx_name_on_key)
VALUES ('default', 'test', 'users', 'user_id', 'first|last', 'PRIMARY');
```

and launch the engine with `INSTALL PLUGIN daemon_memcached soname "libmemcached.so";`, you will find this error in mysql.log file:

```
InnoDB_Memcached: column 6 in the entry for config table 'containers' in database 'innodb_memcache' has an invalid NULL value
Failed to initialize instance. Error code: 13
```

So you should define columns for `flags`, `cas` and `expiry`, this way:

```
CREATE TABLE test.users (
  `user_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  flags int,
  cas bigint unsigned,
  expiry int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO innodb_memcache.containers 
(name, db_schema, db_table, key_columns,
value_columns, flags, cas_column, expire_time_column, unique_idx_name_on_key)
VALUES ('default', 'test', 'users', 'user_id', 'first|last', 'flags', 'cas', 'expiry', 'PRIMARY');
```

Then, when you reenable the plugin, it will start working.

```
telnet localhost 11222
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
set key 0 3600 8
John|Doe
STORED
```

And querying the database:

```
mysql> select * from test.users;
+---------+-------+------+-------+------+------------+
| user_id | first | last | flags | cas  | expiry     |
+---------+-------+------+-------+------+------------+
| key     | John  | Doe  |     0 |   50 | 1495534750 |
+---------+-------+------+-------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```